# How to create web page in sharepoint using REST API?

Tags: api, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a web page under my sharepoint site. I'm able to create Document Folders and upload files inside those folders using REST API but not able to find an API to create a web page. Can someone give me API which helps to create web pages in sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Rest Request to create a web page in SharePoint Site Pages library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CreateWikiPage();

function CreateWikiPage() {

    // Get Server relative url of Web(site)
    var WebServerRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

    // Provide Internal name of the library here
    var DocuentLibraryInternalName = "SitePages";

    // Provide name of the wiki page to be created
    var NewPageName = "NewRESTWikipage.aspx";

    // Form relative url of the new page. This will be used in function below
    var NewFileUrl = WebServerRelativeUrl + "/" + DocuentLibraryInternalName + "/" + NewPageName;

    $.ajax({

        // "templateFileType" values in below method
        // StandardPage. The value = 0.
        // WikiPage. The value = 1.
        // FormPage. The value = 2.

        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + WebServerRelativeUrl + "/" + DocuentLibraryInternalName + "')/Files/AddTemplateFile(urlOfFile='" + NewFileUrl + "',templateFileType=1)",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Failed");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry for sharing this code. Can you help me in adding paragraphs and images to web page. How can i add Images, Headings, Paragraphs and other page components to a web page?

Comment: How can i  create modern web pages and add web parts to it using API?